# Check if an object's immediately inherits from constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, types

The `instanceof` operator is not suitable for purposes that require only a value's parent in the inheritance chain to be checked.

Here is an instance where using `instanceof` to check an object's type returns positives that are false for the above:

```
{} instanceof Object; // returns true, the desired result
[] instanceof Object; // returns true, not the desired result
```

`instanceof` checks if whatever is on the right-hand side exists anywhere in the prototype chain of whatever is on the left-hand side. That is as intended, but if I want to know if a value is a plain object, for example. If I have:

- a prototype/class `Interrupt`,
- a prototype/class `HardwareInterrupt` that inherits from `Interrupt`,
- a prototype/class `SoftwareInterrupt` that inherits from `Interrupt`,
- a prototype/class `MaskableInterrupt` that inherits from `HardwareInterrupt`,
- and a prototype/class `NonmaskableInterrupt` that inherits from `HardwareInterrupt`,

then if I want to know whether or not an object is immediately below `Interrupt` in the hierarchy, `instanceof` can return an inaccurate result like `Nonmaskable instanceof Interrupt` evaluating to `true`. What way will only check an object's immediate ancestor prototype/class against a given prototype/class?

What's the right terminology to use to speak of what an object was instantiated from, anyway? While writing this question I wanted to say "type", but I realized that it's also valid to say, as an example, a maskable interrupt is a type of hardware interrupt (though I can think of examples where using "type" like this would be incorrect). And since there are prototypes and classes in JavaScript, is there a word that can be swapped in for writing "prototype/class"?

Comment: Why not directly perform the `typeof` test with the more specific type? The way the operator works makes sense given the typical meaning of inheritance; a `NonmaskableInterrupt` instance *is* an `Interrupt` instance.

Comment: @Pointy `typeof` would not tell me what an object was instantiated from (e.g., `typeof []` does not return `Array`). I already acknowledged that `instanceof` works the way it's supposed to.

Comment: Does `Object.getPrototypeOf()` help?

Answer (score 1):

> Since there are prototypes and classes in JavaScript, is there a word that can be swapped in for writing "prototype/class"?

The term prototype refers to the prototype object. The term class refers to either the js object that represents the class, i.e. the constructor function, or it refers to the whole thing consisting of the constructor, the prototype, and the methods. So you can just use the word "class" in the broad sense.

> What way will only check an object's immediate ancestor prototype/class against a given prototype/class?

You can either check for the constructor, assuming that your prototype objects are properly set up:

```
 interruptObject.constructor == Interrupt
```

or you can check for the prototype object directly:

```
 Object.getPrototypeOf(interruptObject) == Interrupt.prototype
```

I would however avoid both of these, and rather have a method `isNeitherHardwareNorSoftwareInterrupt` (or whatever exactly you are looking for) that returns a boolean, and implement it accordingly on `Interrupt` and its subclasses.

Comment: The stuff about interrupts was an example. Using a method like `isNeitherHardwareNorSoftwareInterrupt` is unworkable if I'm looking for a way to check this for any given pair of object and prototype/class. Also, I do not think that your answer to the first question you quoted is actually an answer to that question.

Comment: @Melab Then what is your actual use case? Modeling the interrupts with inheritance is indeed not a good example, it hardly makes sense to check for an interrupt that's neither a `HardwareInterrupt` nor a `SoftwareInterrupt` since there's not a third category of interrupts. But my advice stands, use a descriptive method for the property that you're trying to check - following the open-closed principle.

Comment: @Melab I think the answer to your question about a replacement for "prototype/class" is to use the term "class" in the broad sense.